# I'm working on small word-studying program and it works, but it lags and does mistakes

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm trying to make a small word-studying app, that would help me to study the Norwegian language. I use Python for my code and QT-designer for design. Right now I use two libraries: PyQt5 and random.

My app opens in a window and it has two text lines: one for the "foreign" word and one for a word in my language. Right now it's not finished so the code works like that:

It opens a text file, randomly chooses a row, takes the first word, and inserts it in the lineEdit place. Then I can from the keyboard write the same text and the process will be repeated - it will find a new word in the text file.

You can try this code and see that it works, but however, it lags and shuts down automatically sometimes. I don't know the reason, maybe you could tell me why it does.

The code - here I import libraries and open my txt file:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import random


file = open('word_list.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
```

Here is the class of program window with functions in it:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 500)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 500))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: qradialgradient(spread:pad, cx:0.5, cy:0.499727, radius:1.119, fx:0.822, fy:0.227, stop:0 rgba(164, 0, 145, 255), stop:1 rgba(117, 200, 248, 255));")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 480))
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.formLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.formLayout_2.setLabelAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.formLayout_2.setFormAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.formLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.formLayout_2.setHorizontalSpacing(0)
        self.formLayout_2.setVerticalSpacing(50)
        self.formLayout_2.setObjectName("formLayout_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 80))
        self.label.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 80))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("SansSerif")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setKerning(False)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferDefault)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n" "      border: 2px solid #9930aa; \n" "    border-radius: 10px;\n" "    background-color: rgb(212, 197, 223);\n" "    background-color: rgb(219, 220, 235);\n" "    color: rgb(10, 10, 84);\n" "}")
        self.label.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Panel)
        self.label.setLineWidth(0)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setWordWrap(False)
        self.label.setIndent(-1)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.formLayout_2.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.label)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 80))
        self.lineEdit.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 80))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit{\n" "      border: 2px solid #9930aa; \n" "    border-radius: 10px;\n" "    background-color: rgb(212, 197, 223);\n" "    background-color: rgb(219, 220, 235);\n" "    color: rgb(10, 10, 84);\n" "}")
        self.lineEdit.setMaxLength(30)
        self.lineEdit.setCursorPosition(0)
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.formLayout_2.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setBuddy(self.label)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        
        self.move_rand_row(file)
        self.get_task_word(file)
        self.lineEdit.textEdited.connect(lambda: self.check(self.get_word()))
        

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))

    def check(self, word):
        if (word == self.label.text()):
            self.move_rand_row(file)
            self.get_task_word(file)
            self.lineEdit.setText("")

    def get_word(self):
        word = self.lineEdit.text()
        return word
    
    def get_task_word(self, file):
        old_pos = file.tell()
        new_pos = old_pos
        check_ch = file.read(1)
        while (check_ch != '-'):
            check_ch = file.read(1)
            new_pos = new_pos + 1
        word_len = new_pos - old_pos
        file.seek(old_pos)
        word = file.read(word_len)
        self.label.setText(word)        
        
    def move_rand_row(self, file):
        file.seek(0)
        quant = file.readline()
        pos = random.randint(0, int(quant))
        for i in range(pos):
            file.readline()
```

And the ending:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
    
file.close()
```

The text file has name "word_list.txt" and includes:

```
5
å besøke-        навещать
å bestille-      заказать
å bety-          значить
å bli-           становиться
å bo-            жить
```

First number in the text file is the number of rows with words

That was the whole code. Now I will explain what functions "check", "get_word", "get_task_word", "move_rand_row" do.

The function "get_word" returns the word from the lineEdit text holder:

```
def get_word(self):
        word = self.lineEdit.text()
        return word
```

The function "check" checks if the text from lineEdit (word) equals the label text and if it does, then it calls move_rand_row() and get_tesk_word(), also it clear the lineEdit:

```
def check(self, word):
        if (word == self.label.text()):
            self.move_rand_row(file)
            self.get_task_word(file)
            self.lineEdit.setText("")
```

The function "move_rand_row" puts the pointer at the beginning of a random row (1 of 5 in my situation):

```
def move_rand_row(self, file):
        file.seek(0)
        quant = file.readline()
        pos = random.randint(0, int(quant))
        for i in range(pos):
            file.readline()
```

The function "get_task_word" takes all text before "-" symbol and inserts it in the Label text:

```
def get_task_word(self, file):
        old_pos = file.tell()
        new_pos = old_pos
        check_ch = file.read(1)
        while (check_ch != '-'):
            check_ch = file.read(1)
            new_pos = new_pos + 1
        word_len = new_pos - old_pos
        file.seek(old_pos)
        word = file.read(word_len)
        self.label.setText(word)
```

Also this line can be important, because it creates a signal every time I change text in lineEdit and starts the "check" function.

```
self.lineEdit.textEdited.connect(lambda: self.check(self.get_word()))
```

As I said - it works, but unfortunately lags.

Comment: Some important notes: 1. avoid repeating code to explain it: reference it (i.e. name the function) or use code comments; 2. you're using `file` both as global and as argument, which is inconsistent and doesn't make a lot of sense; globals should be avoided anyway, prefer instance attributes instead; 3. unless the file changes during runtime, it makes little sense to continuously access it: just store its values; 4. `check()` always uses the return of `get_word()`, so either call `get_word()` *inside* `check()`, or use a separate function: use lambdas when they are actually effective/required;

Comment: Finally, and this also important, pyuic generated files should *never* be manually modified (nor mimicked or "merged" in your code) and the warning you ignored and removed from that file also tells that. Doing it is considered bad practice and shouldn't be done for a lot of reasons, unless you really, **really** know what you're doing. Those files are intended to be used *as they are* and just imported in order to be used for composition or multiple inheritance. Read more about this in the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: More to the point: don't try to write c in python. The file-reading code reduces to: `words = dict(map(str.strip, n.split('-')) for n in file if '-' in n)`. And the word-selection code reduces to: `word = random.choice(list(words))`. Hwoever, a much better long-term solution would be to store the word-mappings as [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your random number generator is reaching beyond the last line which is making your while loop run forever because it never finds a `-` character after the last line.

Changing the range to one less than what you have I think will solve your problem.

For example:

```
def move_rand_row(self, file):
    file.seek(0)
    quant = file.readline()
    pos = random.randint(0, int(quant) - 1)  # <-- changed this
    for i in range(pos):
        file.readline()
```

Comment: Or just use [`randrange(int(quant))`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange).